# Calculate the conjugancy classes for $D_4$

Tags: group-theory

Calculate the conjugancy classes for $D_4$

$$D_4=\{e,r,r^2,r^3,s,sr,sr^2,sr^3\}$$ The conjugancy class of $e$ is just $\{e\}$. To find the conjugancy class of $r^n$, note that when we conjugate $r^n$ by $r^m$ we get $$r^mr^nr^{-m}=r^n \forall m$$ and when we conjugate $r^n$ by $sr^m$ we get $$sr^mr^nsr^m=sr^msr^{-n}r^m=ssr^{-m}r^{-n}r^m=r^{-n} \forall m$$ (Note that since each reflection $sr^m$ has order $2$, $(sr^m)^{-1}=sr^m$.) Thus the conjugacy class of each of $r^n$ contains $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$. In the case of $D_4$, this gives us the classes

$\{r,r^3\}$ and $\{1,r^2\}$

To find the conjugacy class of s, we compute that when we conjugate $s$ by $r^m$ we get $$r^msr^{-m}=sr^{-2m} \forall m$$ andd when we conjugate $s$ by $sr^m$ we get $$sr^mssr^{-m}=s \forall m$$ Since $m=1,2,3$, $2m=2,1$ since we have to take $2m \,mod (4)$. Thus all the reflections form a single conjugancy class $$\{s,sr,sr^2,sr^3\}$$ Since all the reflections are in this conjugancy class, we don't need to compute the conjugacy class of any of the other reflections. Therefore, $D_4$ has $4$ conjugacy classes listed above.

Comment: You're close, but your last steps are not quite right beginning with "Since $m=1, 2, 3$...". There are actually $5$ conjugacy classes, the remaining two being $\{s, sr^{2}\}$ and $\{sr, sr^{3}\}$.